# Language-Ext, How to use applicatives in c#?

Tags: c#-to-f#, language-ext

Hi I am building a sample of f# from https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world-3/
in c#.

My code is as below,

```
 public class CustomerId : NewType<CustomerId, int> { public CustomerId(int id) : base(id) { } }

    public class EmailAddress : NewType<EmailAddress, string> { public EmailAddress(string email) : base(email) { } }

    public class Customer : Record<Customer>
    {
        public readonly CustomerId Id;
        public readonly EmailAddress Email;
        public Customer(CustomerId id, EmailAddress email)
        {
            Id = id;
            Email = email;
        }
    }

    public static class CustomerConstructor
    {
        public static Result<CustomerId> CreateCustomerId(int id)
        {
            if (id > 0) return new Result<CustomerId>.Success(new CustomerId(id));
            else return new Result<CustomerId>.Error(new[] { "invalid id" });
        }

        public static Result<EmailAddress> CreateCustomerEmail(string email)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) return new Result<EmailAddress>.Error(new[] { "empty email" });
            else if (!email.Contains("@")) return new Result<EmailAddress>.Error(new[] { "invalid email" });
            else return new Result<EmailAddress>.Success(new EmailAddress(email));
        }
    }

    public abstract class Result<A>
    {
        public class Success : Result<A>
        {
            public readonly A Value;

            public Success(A value)
            {
                Value = value;
            }
        }

        public class Error : Result<A>
        {
            public readonly Arr<string> Errors;

            public Error(IEnumerable<string> errors)
            {
                Errors = errors.ToArr();
            }
        }

    }

public static class ResultModule
{
    public static UnitTest1.Result<A> Return<A>(this UnitTest1.Result<A> self, A a)
    {
        return new UnitTest1.Result<A>.Success(a);

    }

    public static UnitTest1.Result<A> Return<A>(A a)
    {
        return new UnitTest1.Result<A>.Success(a);

    }

    public static UnitTest1.Result<B> Select<A, B>(this UnitTest1.Result<A> self, Func<A, B> map)
        => Map<A, B>(self, map);

    public static UnitTest1.Result<B> Map<A, B>(this UnitTest1.Result<A> self, Func<A, B> map)
    {
        if (self is UnitTest1.Result<A>.Success)
        {
            var sx = (UnitTest1.Result<A>.Success)self;
            return new UnitTest1.Result<B>.Success(map(sx.Value));
        }
        else
        {
            var er = (UnitTest1.Result<A>.Error)self;
            return new UnitTest1.Result<B>.Error(er.Errors);
        }
    }

    public static UnitTest1.Result<B> ApplyMine<A, B>(this UnitTest1.Result<A> self, UnitTest1.Result<Func<A, B>> apply)
    {
        if (apply is UnitTest1.Result<Func<A, B>>.Success && self is UnitTest1.Result<A>.Success)
        {
            var f = (UnitTest1.Result<Func<A, B>>.Success)apply;
            var x = (UnitTest1.Result<A>.Success)self;

            return new UnitTest1.Result<B>.Success(f.Value(x.Value));
        }

        if (apply is UnitTest1.Result<Func<A, B>>.Error && self is UnitTest1.Result<A>.Success)
        {
            var f = (UnitTest1.Result<Func<A, B>>.Error)apply;
            return new UnitTest1.Result<B>.Error(f.Errors);
        }

        if (apply is UnitTest1.Result<Func<A, B>>.Success && self is UnitTest1.Result<A>.Error)
        {
            var x = (UnitTest1.Result<A>.Error)self;
            return new UnitTest1.Result<B>.Error(x.Errors);
        }

        if (apply is UnitTest1.Result<Func<A, B>>.Error && self is UnitTest1.Result<A>.Error)
        {
            var f = (UnitTest1.Result<Func<A, B>>.Error)apply;
            var x = (UnitTest1.Result<A>.Error)self;
            return new UnitTest1.Result<B>.Error(f.Errors.Concat(x.Errors));
        }

        return default(UnitTest1.Result<B>);//fn should never hit here
    }

    public static UnitTest1.Result<B> Bind<A, B>(this UnitTest1.Result<A> self, Func<A, UnitTest1.Result<B>> bind)
    {
        if (self is UnitTest1.Result<A>.Success)
        {
            var sx = (UnitTest1.Result<A>.Success)self;
            return bind(sx.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            var er = (UnitTest1.Result<A>.Error)self;
            return new UnitTest1.Result<B>.Error(er.Errors);
        }
    }

    public static UnitTest1.Result<C> SelectMany<A, B, C>(this UnitTest1.Result<A> self, Func<A, UnitTest1.Result<B>> bind, Func<A, B, C> project)
    {
        var bound = Bind<A, B>(self, bind);
        if (bound is UnitTest1.Result<B>.Success)
        {
            var sxA = (UnitTest1.Result<A>.Success)self;
            var sxB = (UnitTest1.Result<B>.Success)bound;
            return new UnitTest1.Result<C>.Success(project(sxA.Value, sxB.Value));

        }
        else
        {
            var er = (UnitTest1.Result<A>.Error)self;
            return new UnitTest1.Result<C>.Error(er.Errors);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: UnitTest1 is the namespace added (as there is a Result type in LanguageExt)

For the code above my test are as below

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestApplicativeValidation()
{
    var goodId = 1;
    var badId = 0;
    var goodEmail = "test@example.com";
    var badEmail = "example.com";

    Func<CustomerId, EmailAddress, Customer> createCustomer = (id, email) => new Customer(id, email);
    var idResult = CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerId(goodId);
    var emailResult = CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerEmail(goodEmail);
    var createCustomer1 = ResultModule.Return(createCustomer);

    //ResultModule.ApplyMine(idResult, )




}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMonadaicValidation()
{
    var goodId = 1;
    var badId = 0;
    var goodEmail = "test@example.com";
    var badEmail = "example.com";

    var goodCust = from id in CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerId(goodId)
                   from email in CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerEmail(goodEmail)
                   select new Customer(id, email);

    var badCust = from id in CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerId(badId)
                  from email in CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerEmail(badEmail)
                  select new Customer(id, email);

}
```

The Monadiac test runs as expeced and its all find, But I am unable to write test to check the applicative scenario as in the link,

```
let (<!>) = Result.map
let (<*>) = Result.apply

// applicative version
let createCustomerResultA id email = 
    let idResult = createCustomerId id
    let emailResult = createEmailAddress email
    createCustomer <!> idResult <*> emailResult
// int -> string -> Result<CustomerInfo>
```

Can any one guide me put some insights here, we have a linq expressions that automagically uses the select / select many, what in the case of applicative style?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry Mat, that question was posted after hours of frustration to get the code work! The question is what code must be put in the TestApplicativeValidation() method to get it work.  As you see I created a Result class which fulfil the law of monad, I was unsure on how to use the ApplyMine function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `Validation` type in language-ext to implement the example.  I won't do all the work for you, but you can take a look at [one of the units tests](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/master/LanguageExt.Tests/ValidationTests.cs) which has a real-world example of using the applicative behaviour of the `Validation` type.

Most of the core types in language-ext support applicative behaviour [through the `apply` function](https://louthy.github.io/language-ext/LanguageExt.Core/LanguageExt/Prelude_.htm#apply<A,%20B,%20C>).

Comment: Dear Louthy , The point was just like linq expression for monad using (from m in...) , is there any thing we can do for applicatives. thanks for your timely response.

Comment: LINQ can't be used for applicative behaviour because the terms are dependent on each other in LINQ.  So `from x in ... from y in ... select x + y` means `y` depends on `x` and the `select` depends on `x` and `y`.  Applicatives essentially all calculate 'in parallel', i.e. they're independent values.  So LINQ can only be used for functor and monadic behaviour.  For `Validation` I use tuples to make it slightly easier to work with (take a look at line 158 of the unit test link above).  But for non Validation types you need to use `apply(op, left1, apply(op, left2, apply(op, right)))`

Comment: @louthster: It's a shame the LINQ `join` clause requires an`on ... equals` clause, otherwise applicative could be represented as `from x in ... join y in .... select ...`, where as desired, `join` does not allow dependency of later clauses on earlier clauses. Idea from [an old blog post](http://tomasp.net/blog/idioms-in-linq.aspx/)

Answer (score 1):

I ve found the right implementation of ApplyMine function above. Below is the test case of applicative.

```
  [TestMethod]
        public void TestApplicativeValidation()
        {
            var goodId = 1;
            var badId = 0;
            var goodEmail = "test@example.com";
            var badEmail = "example.com";

            Func<CustomerId, EmailAddress, Customer> createCustomer = (id, email) => new Customer(id, email);

            /*
            var idResult = CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerId(goodId);
            var emailResult = CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerEmail(goodEmail);
            var goodCustomer = idResult.Lift2(emailResult, createCustomer);
            */

            var good = CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerId(goodId).Lift2(CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerEmail(goodEmail), createCustomer);

            var bad22 = CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerId(badId).Lift2(CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerEmail(badEmail), createCustomer);

            var bad1 = CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerId(goodId).Lift2(CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerEmail(badEmail), createCustomer);

            var bad2 = CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerId(badId).Lift2(CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerEmail(goodEmail), createCustomer);


        }
```

Here is the Lift2 implementation added to the extension class / module.

```
 public static UnitTest1.Result<C> Lift2<A, B, C>(this UnitTest1.Result<A> self, UnitTest1.Result<B> other, Func<A, B, C> lift2)
        {
            Func<A, Func<B, C>> lifter = a => b => lift2(a, b);

            var aBakedIn = self.ApplyMine(ResultModule.Return(lifter));
            return other.ApplyMine(aBakedIn);
        }
```

In csharp there is no expression for applicative style programming where as for monadiac style we have linq

```
  var goodCust = from id in CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerId(goodId)
                           from email in CustomerConstructor.CreateCustomerEmail(goodEmail)
                           select new Customer(id, email);
```

, It will more concise to call lift2 explicitly with 2 monads and a 2 parameter function. As like language-ext does through Prelute. I decided to follow "dot into notation" in c sharp as well when using functional constructs.

This article came to rescue when I was having brainfarts!
http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html

Comment: http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.